# JHipster project update to java 8

Tags: jhipster

I am  working in an project made with Jhipster choosing Java 7 because the function of **HotReloading** but when jhipster and Java 8 HotRealoding  works well i'll like make an update to Java 8

There is an easy way to do this by command line or pom config? or I´LL  need to do some change in the code ?

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your .yo-rc.json configuration file, and run the generator again on your project, choosing the Java 8 configuration.
Then you can use the usual Git tools to do a "diff" between both implementations. Using Java 8 means you have some new APIs, the lambdas, etc, that will make the code more concise.